# Webpack v5 output library configuration for turning es6 into commonjs

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

If my bundle entrypoint consists of:

```
export default function test() { console.log('Test was successful!'); }
```

& I have another file I want to run that consists of:

```
var test = require('/path/to/bundle');
test();
```

then what is the [Webpack v5 output.library configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) that I need to get this to work?

I've tried numerous suggestions from https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2030 & `var test` has been `undefined` with every single one of them.